# Не добавляется класс active с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Сделал на WP вывод постов в аккордеонах, все работает, но у меня до этого в верстке висел скрипт который должен был навешивать класс active в div с классом panel panel-default, необходимый мне для оформления css, в верстке все работало, но на WP просто не срабатывает и класс не добавляет, в инспекторе ошибок нету и скрипт присутствует
Вот собственно цикл аккордеона

```
                      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                        </a>
                                                <span class="collapsed caret" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="caret"></span>
                                    </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <?php the_content(); ?>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                        </div>
```

а это сам скрипт, он подключен но не работает

```
(function () {

    $(".panel").on("show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse", function (e) {
        if (e.type == 'show') {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: хтмл надо предоставлять без php-вставок

Comment: Это WP, о чем ты?